# Parsing Escape character with delimiter in csv into same field in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a following text in csv file with delimiter as ','

```
Vliesbehang_0\,52&1\,04,103
```

I want the below output

```
Vliesbehang_0\,52&1\,04 | 103
```

but when I am doing the bq load it is ignoring the escape character and output I am getting is

```
Vliesbehang_0\ | 52&1\ | 04 | 103
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should replace the last delimiter with another symbol, like a semicolon (;) or a tab (\t). After that, you can use the option `--field_delimiter` to specify the new delimiter.

Comment: yes I tried that and it is working as well in unix it will become more of a manual process . but the file here is in csv.gz format is there any way we can do this in python ?

Comment: You can use the function call os process from python call,  using the gzip tool to extract the gz file. After that, you read the extracted file and write to a new file with your delimiter, and call gzip utility to compress the file one more time. And voila, you can use bq command to upload your new csv.gz to BQ. I prefer to write a python script to replace delimiter in csv file, then write a shell script to unzip gz file, call python script, zip new file and transfer to BQ using bq command.